# Deriving group velocity formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A formula for the group velocity of waves is:

$u=k*dv/dk + v$

But then, since $k=2π/λ$, this equation can be rewritten as:

$u=v-dv/dλ*λ$

But how? My attempt:

$k*dv/dk$ = $((2π/λ)*dv/d(2π/λ)$

Then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with:

$$ u = k \frac{dv}{dk} + v $$

and use the chain rule:

$$ \frac{dv}{dk} = \frac{dv}{d\lambda} \frac{d\lambda}{dk} \tag{1} $$

And $\lambda = 2\pi/k$, so:

$$ \frac{d\lambda}{dk} = -\frac{2\pi}{k^2} $$

Substituting this into equation (1) and multiplying by $k$ we get:

$$ k \frac{dv}{dk} = - \frac{dv}{d\lambda} \frac{2\pi}{k} = - \frac{dv}{d\lambda} \lambda $$

And therefore:

$$ u = - \frac{dv}{d\lambda} \lambda + v $$

as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "then what" part of the question, note that $d (2\pi/\lambda)=\frac{-2\pi}{\lambda^2} d \lambda$. Then $(2π/λ)*dv/d(2π/λ) = (2π/λ) (\frac{-2\pi}{\lambda^2})^{-1} dv/d \lambda = -\lambda dv/d \lambda $. This gives you your answer.